# EF Core randomly crawls user tables on API requests after migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, serilog

After migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1, EF Core will randomly start crawling Users-table and make hundreds/thousands of logs (see picture - specific log is in bottom highlighted with blue).

I have followed migration guides from Microsoft, e.g. 2.2 to 3.0 and 3.0 to 3.1. (Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

**Important info**: This has started happening **after** I added `app.UseAuthorization();` in `Startup.cs`, which wasn't there before.

Any ideas what could trigger this?

It results in the following error after maybe 30 seconds: **504 Gateway Time-out**

I am using NuGet `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`.

**Update** Seems to happen on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).` So eradicating that exception should fix it, but I would be very careful to push this migration to the production server, if somehow an exception can cause EF Core to start crawling endlessly.

[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with EF Core. Some other code (e.g. from authorization pipeline) is generating calls to EF Core,  which of course does what it is requested.

Comment: @IvanStoev After more research, it looks like it starts to happen, after the code throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`

Comment: @IvanStoev If you are interested, the problem was when using Serilog to log exceptions with `destructureObjects` set to true, for some reason. So when an exception was caught in a `try-catch` and then logged, it started to crawl endlessly.

Comment: It just proves the problem is not from/with EF Core, but other code/library (as I wrote in the previous comment).

Comment: @IvanStoev Of course, it was just to inform you if you had interest in what was the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when using Serilog to log exceptions with `destructureObjects` set to true, for some reason. So when an exception was caught in a `try-catch` and then logged with `destructureObjects` set to true, it started to crawl endlessly.

Comment: _endlessly_ Literally or figuratively? I believe there's a controllable max depth. IIRC it was reduced in recent times. (And +1 for self-answering)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Mostly figuratively, but we stopped it manually every time it happened (probably a minute or two at most before we did so). I would definitely be interested in reading more on this or what could cause it, if you know of other cases or similar. We didn't have luck with setting max depth, but solved it with a DestructuringPolicy explicitly for exceptions, since they were the ones that caused problems.